# Change ID App in Qt

Tags: android, qt, mobile, qt5, qt-creator

Well.. I have a big problem my app id is "org.qtproject.example.test". I want to change to "com.mycompany.myapp". I was looking at the whole project and there is no way to change it. How do you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the package name in the Android manifest file.

manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.mycompany.myapp" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0.0"

Answer (score 1):

Open the `AndroidManifest.xml` file of your project in Creator and it's the first setting in the manifest editor form.

Also, from `QGuiApplication` see the `setOrganizationName()`, `setOrganizationDomain()` and `setApplicationName()` functions.